# Best Practices for creating and merging branch in SVN

Tags: svn

Currently, we are using SVN for version control. We create a branch and develop all new feature in branch and tester also test using branch version build.

At the last we merge the branch in a trunk and deploy in the Live from trunk.

If some bug found in Live then we fixed in branch and merge only that version in the trunk and then we deploy trunk build in Live.

In short Live build always from trunk.

I know this is not good Practice. Just want to know, which are the best practises for creating the branch when should be merged with trunk?

Any good article on this please share.

Thanks

Comment: https://git-scm.com/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is OK. Trunk would be main body of development and is guaranteed to be extremely stable at all times. You should merge branch with trunk only if bugs are tested perfectly. New branch is usually created every specific time interval (e.g. month) or if some major changes are planned to do.

You should use **Tag** also. Tag is a point in time on the trunk or a branch that you wish to preserve. Then, it's easier to get back to stable point (major release, alpha, beta, RC or RTM).